# Combination of SOQL Statements String with Boolean Attributes

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

Do you have an idea on how can i combine the following SOQL statements into just one i tried several options and by creating the two entries i was able to get it to work.. i'm fairly new to APEX development and i really want to do the right thing i know that too many Select statements may cause issues for the system..  ! Thanks for your help !!

```
    return [select Id, OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItem
            where OpportunityId =:opportunityId  
            and CARE_BMI_Sync_Behaviour__c = 'Sync ON'];        
    return [select Id, OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItem
            where OpportunityId =:opportunityId  
            and HasQuantitySchedule = False AND HasRevenueSchedule = False];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the rows that would be returned by those two separate queries then you'd want to OR the different pieces, e.g.

```
return [select Id, OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItem
        where OpportunityId =:opportunityId AND
        (( CARE_BMI_Sync_Behaviour__c = 'Sync ON') OR
         ( HasQuantitySchedule = False AND HasRevenueSchedule = False)) ];
```

Comment: Hi SuperFell.. ! Unfortunately this doesn't work.. for some reason in the Select statement in not evaluating the conditions separately.. ! I'm not getting any syntax errors or anything just the result is not the one that i'm looking for.. ! Any other ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.. for some reason in the Select statement in not evaluating the conditions separately.. ! I'm not getting any syntax errors or anything just the result is not the one that i'm looking for.. ! Any other ideas ? Thanks !